# In-house person identification system

Tags: sensor, bluetooth, proximity-sensor

For my smart home, I am trying to develop a system that allows me to identify which person is located in which room.
I am a software engineer but I don't really have experience with hardware development etc.

The system should work with as little action required by the user as possible.

I ruled out RFID because of its short range. I ruled out facial recognition because of the creepy feeling it leaves with everyone if your house can see you.

I am now thinking of using Bluetooth:
Each person that needs to be identified wears a Bluetooth sender and each room contains a Bluetooth scanner.

Questions:

1. Can this actually work?
2. Is this the best option I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your Bluetooth suggestion is the most viable one.  However I would use the new BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) standard as it will reduce the current consumption of the senders considerably.

You refer to the devices carried by the users as senders and the fixed room devices as scanners; the actual Bluetooth nomenclature is masters for the fixed room Bluetooth devices, and slaves for the senders since they will be going in and out of the network as people arrive and leave.

In addition to the senders and receivers, you are going to need a host Bluetooth device that receive all of the information from the fixed room devices.

The problem with Bluetooth (or any radio-based scheme) is that multiple room receivers will "see" each of the senders since the range will probably be at least 10m inside a house.

However it's possible to narrow things down using a RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indication).  Each master can compute its own RSSI value for the slave, and then these could be sent to a host computer which could do a triangulation calculation.   Here is a paper [written on this topic](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa06/cse237a/finalproj/almula.pdf).

Note that it is not necessary to actually do a Bluetooth pairing to get the RSSI value; one just needs to execute the command to do an inquiry and each of the RSSI values will be returned along with the MAC ID of the devices.   This is very convenient, since it means you never have to actually pair up any of the slaves with any of the fixed room Bluetooth masters.

We're not really supposed to provide specific product information here, I'll just say I have used the Bluegiga BLE113 on a couple of projects successfully.

Note: Beside BLE, I should mention that ZigBee is also an alternative.  It works in the same 2.4 GHz frequency range as Bluetooth and Wi-Fi.  It has the advantage that it uses a mesh network as a network model, which makes it easier to hop from one node to another (for BLE, you will have to engineer that yourself -- mesh networks are coming to BLE, but are not here yet).

The main disadvantage with ZigBee, as I see it, is there is no built-in transceiver in either PCs or Smartphones, like there is for BLE.  Why is that important?  *If you have a smart phone in your pocket, you won't need to carry anything else to be recognized (such as a bracelet).*

Comment: Thank you very much for fixing my nomenclature. Because I used the wrong one, I was unable to find anything using Google... My house will have a central server that coordinates everything going on in the house, so the triangulation is not a problem. Furthermore, the house will have KNX presence detectors which I could use to further improve the result. Do I understand that correctly, that the "host Bluetooth device" isn't actually a Bluetooth receiver or sender but simply some computer?

Comment: No, I did mean the host Bluetooth device to be just that -- a master device that will talk to each of the fixed Bluetooth devices as slaves.  I assumed you didn't want to hardwire each of those back to your central computer.

Comment: Will it do that via Bluetooth? Won't there be a problem in big houses?

Comment: The range of a BLE113 in open air is approximately 80m to 100m (i.e. a football field).  Indoors, I've seen numbers indicating it could be a third of that (25m), but for this discussion lets assume it's only 10m.  So one centrally located Bluetooth transceiver could conceivably cover a 2500 sq ft house all on one floor.  If needed, you could add additional nodes and relay data up yo the host.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. Now I just need to figure out how to actually get started as I don't have hardware experience... :-)

Answer (score 2):

RFID readers are available with 2 antenna ports.  Locating a reader at each door with an antenna in each room for doorways that connect rooms (or inside and outside in the case of home entry doors) and connecting the readers back to a central computer that simply keeps track of movements in and out would easily record / display which RFID tag is in which room currently or at a specific time.  While simple and functional, the cost of this may exceed the cost of a Bluetooth solution.

Comment: What about the short range of just a few centimeters?

Comment: Some of the readers (and antennas) are designed for doorways.  It will read first on one antenna and then the other antenna.  This will indicate which way the person went through the door and therefore which room they are in.  Not where in the room they are, so folks should not feel their privacy is being invaded.  As long as the computer tracks every entry / exit it should know continuously in which room (if any) each of the RFID tags is in.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. But there is still the problem with the short read range, isn't there? Doesn't this approach rely on a specific position of the tag on the person? Or the person actively "showing" the "badge" to the readers or something?

Comment: 13.56MHz passive tags go up to around 5 feet which would handle most "regular" doors.  Gen 2 passive tags will read up to 37 feet or more which would take care of most garage doors.  For things like hanger doors probably have to go to active or at least semi-active tags.  But for most homes, passive tags should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go after people's phones and or most treasured wireless devices.  No one in my family seems to leave a room for very long without one.  I would think it would be difficult to convince them to always carry a little separate bluetooth device unless it really added some value to their life.

You could place bluetooth beacons in each room, or several per room even.  Then have a background app on the phones look for them periodically.  They can use the relative receive strength to get a rough idea of position.   Then they can update this information to your local/remote server sending out time and position or time and beacon strength periodically.

Just my thought, this way you can just make cheap battery powered beacons and stick them everywhere.  If you do it the other way you have to put enough smarts and cost into each sensor to detect presence and then network it's way back to your controller.

Hmm remind me to make this later and hope NEST buys me for a $1B dollars :)

Comment: Battery powered stick-em-anywhere beacons already exist.  Not so sure about "cheap".

Comment: I see them at $9 quantity 1?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It wouldn't work in my scenario though. My phone is at my desk most of the day, even when I am elsewhere in the house.